# Django passing context in JsonResponse

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax

I am developing a webpage with filters to filter the results on the page.
A Ajax is called, which sends the filters to my Django back-end. The results are filtered and the data should be passed back to the front-end.

So now I need to pass my results of the models with context to the front-end. This leads to some problems.

My Ajax:

```
$(document).on('change', '#test-form', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    var tags = [];
    $('input[name="tags[]"]:checked').each(function(i){
        return tags[i] = $(this).val();
    });


    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        url: "{% url 'core:jobSearch_nosearch' %}",
        data: {
            tags: tags,
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('yey')
            console.log(data)

        }
    });
});
```

Here my View:

```
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
from django.utils.functional import Promise


class LazyEncoder(DjangoJSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Promise):
            return str(obj)
        return super().default(obj)

def jobSearch(request, **search):
    companies = Company.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ads = Ad.objects.all() 
        search_job = request.GET.get('search')
        if search_job:
            ads = Ad.objects.filter(title__contains=search_job)

        tag_filter = request.POST.getlist('tags[]')
        for tag in tag_filter:
            print(tag)
            ads = ads.filter(tag__name=tag)
            print(ads)
        context = {'companies': companies, 'ads': ads}
        # context = {'companies': list(companies)}
        # context = {'msg': 'Success'}
        # return JsonResponse(serialize('json', ads, cls=LazyEncoder), safe=False)
        return JsonResponse(context)
    else:
        ads = Ad.objects.all()
        context = {'companies': companies, 'ads': ads}
        return render(request, 'core/jobSearch.html', context)
```

As you can see I tried different things in the my view. This `return JsonResponse(serialize('json', ads, cls=LazyEncoder), safe=False)` passes the result of one model. But I have two models which I have to pass to the front-end.

Additionally, I would like to get the data and being able to use it with the html template language.

In this way: (example)

```
{% for a in ads %}
    {% a %}
{% endfor %}
```

Is that even possible with Django and Ajax, or is there another way to filter results and passing them without reloading the page?

Answer (score 0):

django template tag work on rendering html content and you can not pass argument after render page so after loading page you can not use

```
{% for a in ads %}
    {% a %}
{% endfor %}
```

if you have not pass that arguments
you can use api and js for this work
i suggest you  read about [drf](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/)
you can do this work with api and js